# Floating point arithmetic

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-science, numerical-linear-algebra

How can I prove that : a real number has a finite representation in the binary system if and only if it is of the form $$\pm \frac{m}{2^n}$$ where n and m are positive integers.

Answer (score 4):

A representation of a positive number $\alpha$ in the binary system is a series of the form
$$\alpha=\sum_{k=d}^\infty e_k 2^{-k}$$
with $e_k\in \{0,1\}$ and is finite if there is an $n$ such taht $e_k=0$ for all $k>n$, i.e. we simply have
$$\alpha=\sum_{k=d}^n e_k 2^{-k}.$$
Then multiplication with $2^n$ produces
$$2^n\alpha = 2^n\sum_{k=d}^n e_k 2^{-k}= \sum_{k=d}^n e_k 2^{n-k}\in\mathbb Z$$