# Positive real number has a finite number of binary when is in form $ m/2^n $

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Prove that positive real number $ ( x \in \mathbb{R} \ x > 0) $ has a finite number of binary if and only if when is in form $ \frac{m}{2^n} $, where $ m, n \in \mathbb{N} $

I found this solution: [Floating point arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243226/floating-point-arithmetic) 
But I don't understand a few things: 
1) What does it mean: $ \alpha=\sum_{k=d}^\infty e_k 2^{-k} $, why we can use this designation and why $ k = d $, why not $ k = 0 $ ? 
2) What is this $ e_k \in {0, 1} $ 
3) Wherein the step showed that is finite ? 
4) What give us $ 2^n\alpha = 2^n\sum_{k=d}^n e_k 2^{-k}= \sum_{k=d}^n e_k 2^{n-k}\in\mathbb Z $ ?

I added this task, because I can't comment above task. 
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\alpha=\sum_{k=d}^\infty e_k 2^{-k}$ with $e_k\in\{0,1\}$ is the binary expansion of $\alpha$. Starting from $d\in \mathbb Z$ means that $\alpha$ can have  non zero integer part.
Note that $\alpha$ has finite binary expansion if and only if $2^n\alpha\in\mathbb Z$ for some $n\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Ok but I know this formula $ x=(+/-)\sum_{k=0}^\infty e_k2^k $ Why in formula above is $ (...)2^{-k} $ ? And could you answer at 3 and 4 question :) ?

Comment: Your formula holds only for whole numbers i.e. without digits after the point. The formula above is more general.

Comment: What does it depend?

Comment: In your formula you consider only positive power of 2. For expand real numbers, you must consider both positive and negative powers of 2. More precisely, finitely many positive powers and possible all negative powers.

Comment: But in my formula is plus or minut $ x = (+/-) ... $ You looked at them??

Comment: Without lost of generality we can confine yourself to positive numbers only.

Comment: I'm talking about the sign of exponent, not of the number $\alpha $.

Comment: Right, my fault. Could you explain point number three and four? Because I don't understand when we show that $ x $ has a finite number.

Comment: Maybe you've some idea?

Comment: I needn't consider $ m $ in proof ? Because in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243226/floating-point-arithmetic isn't nothing say about m.

Comment: this proof is correct? (proof from these page) And why it's all?

Comment: The proof is correct. Explain yours doubts about the proof: why you don't understand the finiteness of expansion?

Comment: Could you tell me why we mulitiply $ 2 \cdot \alpha $ ? Why this $ 2 $ ? It's last my question.

Comment: If $\alpha $ has at most $ n $ digits after the point then $ m=2^n \alpha $ is a integer and you obtain $\alpha=\frac m{2^n}$.